# Hausdorff methods of summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, reference-request, summation, summation-method

From the book of Boss "Classical and modern methods in summability":

"The class of [Hausdorff methods](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=kZ9cy6XyidEC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=hausdorff%20summability%20methods&source=bl&ots=vlN3k86o11&sig=BF1O_-li0gMH1-lrnrEA6JFOXMs&hl=tr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz0Lnk6vXYAhVGhiwKHVPfD5sQ6AEIXDAG#v=onepage&q&f=false) includes the Hölder, Cesaro and Euler methods. A large number of other matrix methods which play an essential role in summability are Hausdorff methods too."

I wonder if there is any well-known example of Hausdorff methods? For example, circle methods such as [Meyer-Konig or Taylor](https://ac.els-cdn.com/002190459290099A/1-s2.0-002190459290099A-main.pdf?_tid=085a4674-02a6-11e8-9a32-00000aacb362&acdnat=1516977456_fa6ca17dedaa0bb458823cea850f5521)  is an Hausdorff method?